# ionic serve not working after installing ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Recently installed ionic2.

After that when  i try to run/open (i.e. ionic serve)  ionic 1 projects which i have done earlier it is throwing me a message:

> **"WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
>   Uh oh! Looks like you're missing a module in your gulpfile:
>   Cannot find module 'gulp'
>   Do you need to run `npm install`?"**

I have tried installing **bower,gulp, gulp-util**. but nothing worked. has anybody got this issue? can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you tried `npm install` that they have mentioned? If yes and the problem still persists then try following this tutorial of converting ionic 1 to ionic 2 http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-convert-an-ionic-1-application-to-ionic-2/

Comment: did you try turning it off then on :\